# Should we use redux store for storing and managing data from api

Tags: angular, redux, angular7, ngrx-store

I want to know, whether this is useful and even possible to manage and store data that we receive from an API over HTTP.

I am building an admin portal in which i make api calls to fetch data and to moderate the data.

I am using Angular 7 for building my app. I thought about using redux using ngrx but i was stuck on how I can use redux for stoding data that i received from API and for moderating that.

One of the use case is as below:

I receive list of feeds and I want to approve or reject them. 
I have a component "FeedComponent" which takes a feed and display it and there's another component which fetches list of feeds and use multiple "FeedComponents" to display feeds.

Now question is, i can fetch list of feed and add that to store, further i can pass each feed to a "FeedComponent" to display. But when admin approves or reject a feed, how i am supposed to update the store? Should i iterate and change single feed? If yes, then in this way my function will not be pure as i will not be returning new object.

Is using redux for such scenario is advisable?

Comment: Yes, of course you can. Updating the store is handled by your reducer(s). Even if you're updating a single object in an array, your reducer should always return a new state Object that matches your reducer's interface. Reducers are pure functions - no side effects. Ngrx has Effects for side effects that are derived from action dispatches if you need them.

Comment: Could you please point me to any resource, blog or video from where i can learn to do this?

Comment: This is an older article, but it's where I started with Ngrx: https://bodiddlie.github.io/ng-2-toh-with-ngrx-suite/